# MongoDB insert nested data

Tags: json, mongodb, nested

I have data in json format like this:

```
{
     {'rank': 1, 'keyword': 'A'}
     {'rank': 2, 'keyword': 'B'}
     {'rank': 3, 'keyword': 'C'}
}
```

now I would like to store data in MongoDB database, and make the data structure like this:

```
{
   datetime: "2021-01-26T02:35:00+0400",
   data: [
           {'rank': 1, 'keyword': 'A'}
           {'rank': 2, 'keyword': 'B'}
           {'rank': 3, 'keyword': 'C'}
         ]
}
```

Following is my code, however, it stores every single piece of data in one object.
Is it possible to store data in a nested structure?

```
    for r in ranks:
      rank = r.get("rank")
      keyword = r.get("keyword")
        
      result = {"data":[
                            {
                                "rank": rank,
                                "key word": keyword
                            }]
                }
            
    collection.insert_one({"datetime": date_time, "data": result})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use "update" to change the same document
2. Use $push to add the object to the "data" array

example:

```
 collection.update( {"datetime": "2021-01-26T02:35:00+0400"} , { $push:{data:{ rank:4 , keyword:"D" }}}  )
```

will give you:

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("600f0b64419e1279778fe326"),
"datetime" : "2021-01-26T02:35:00+0400",
"data" : [
    { "rank" : 1, "keyword" : "A" },
    { "rank" : 2, "keyword" : "B" },
    { "rank" : 3, "keyword" : "C" },
    { "rank" : 4, "keyword" : "D" }
]
}
```

Also in your python example you seems to execute the single object insert operation  after the loop ... , add the operation inside the loop if you want to add one by one ... , but you may better prepare the whole array of objects and insert it at once ...

In case document with such a datetime do not exist and you would like to insert the data in new document, you must add {upsert:true} to the update operation ...

Comment: thanks for your reply and suggestion!  I've redesigned the data structure by preparing the whole array and insert it.